# numpy indexing doesn't keep shape

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Running

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.arange(1, 5)
a2 = np.arange(2, 6)
a = np.array([a1, a2])
a[a <= 3]
```

results in

```
array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3])
```

Instead I would like to get

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3]])
```

How should I updated the above code? I tried different slicing, `take`, `take_along_axis` to no avail.

PS: please note that above is considered a ragged sequence

> VisibleDeprecationWarning:
> Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a
> list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or
> shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify
> 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
> np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3]])

Comment: Why do you want to create an ndarray who's shape is not well-defined? What information are you trying to attain from `a`?

Comment: You can't produce a ragged sequence with indexing.  The best you can do is iterate by rows.

Comment: @Moosefeather I would like to use the resulting ndarray to index into another ndarray aka. b[a]=1.0 (which also might nit work ...)

Comment: @gliptak Perhaps what you want is `np.where`?

Comment: `arr[bool_array]` always produces a 1d array.  If that isn't clear, you need to reread the basic numpy indexing docs. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing.  And trying to get a ragged array is a strong indicator that whole-array, no-loop, calculation is not possible.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for the pointers. I might have to loop the second dimension as swag2198 proposed (apparently cannot tag two persons ...)

Comment: @Moosefeather looking more into `np.where`

Comment: @gliptak If `b` has the same shape as `a`, try playing around with things like `b = np.where(a <= 3, 64, b)`. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want but it should help. There's also `np.argwhere`

Answer (score 2):

Use python list to store the resulting numpy arrays. As you have already encountered, numpy arrays don't support irregular shapes.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a1 = np.arange(1, 5)
>>> a2 = np.arange(2, 6)
>>> a = np.array([a1, a2])
>>> inds = a <= 3
>>> inds
array([[ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False]])
>>> l = [a[i][inds[i]] for i in range(a.shape[0])]
>>> l
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3])]
```

Comment: i would prefer avoiding per row processing
PS even regular shapes don't work
import numpy as np
a1 = np.arange(1, 5)
a2 = np.arange(1, 5)
a = np.array([a1, a2])
a[a <= 3]
gets
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])

Comment: As @hpaulj pointed out in comments, indexing the array by a boolean array will anyway pick the elements only (in True locations of the boolean) to form the final 1d array. Row processing works as long as you have a regular array `a` ie, all your `a1`, `a2` etc. have the same length.

Answer (score 2):

You could use numpy's [masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.html) for this purpose.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

a1 = np.arange(1, 5)
a2 = np.arange(2, 6)
a = np.array([a1, a2])
a_masked = ma.masked_greater(a, 3)
```

The `masked_greater` function returns a new array in which all values greater than 3 are masked out.

Please note that

> the `numpy.ma` module provides a nearly work-alike replacement for numpy
> that supports data arrays with masks.

So, if you pass a masked array to a function of the `ma` module, it will operate only on array elements that are not masked out.

Comment: yes, I also tried masked arrays. I will check if they for 'downstream" processing

Answer (score -1):

If you want to construct a one-dimensional array whose elements are lists, run:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3]], dtype="object")
assert a.shape == (2,)
```

If you want to construct a two-dimensional array then `a1` and `a2` must have equal lengths, which is not the case in your example.